# Using ^ inside strings in python

Tags: python-3.x, math, mathjax

Hi there I am new to this.

Code:

```
display(Math('4^4.2'))
```

Output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong. The decimal is not up on the exponents

I have tried to keep the exponents nicely formatted including the decimals but the decimals came down.

Comment: Try `'4^{4.2}'`.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also remember to properly tag your post. This looks like a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways of achieving a power (exponent) in python.

here are the two most common ways.

- use the `**` and not `^`.
- use the `pow()` function

```py
result = 4**4.2
print(result)

result = pow(4, 4.2)
print(result)
```

Comment: I think they're using MathJax or some variant, so they're not looking for actual arithmetic exponent, but just for pretty displaying of equations. Their question is not really related to python at all.

Comment: @Stef,  you could be right.  i am answering on the basis that `python` is a tag and i see a jupyter notebook in the image provided. If it is `mathjax`, then it is a different language `JavaScript `...

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX doesn't automatically add parentheses like python does. How does it know that (2^2).4 isn't a new notation? Generally you should put braces around the exponent and other things:

```
2^{2.4}
```

Comment: Please offer a better way to write this statement.